# Execute JavaScript function if a subresource request on the page received 401 error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, http-error

Is there some way in JavaScript to know if some subresource that has been included on the page, like an image, css, etc did not end successfully. i.e. is there a way for a page to detect if any of its resource request resulted in 404/401 or any other error.

One solution could be to have an onerror handler on each and every tag but is there some way to catch the error globally for any resource request across the document (XHR, img, link tag, video tag, anything)

I tried:

```
window.onerror = function() {}
```

But this handler does not get called in such cases. Is there some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need to add it to every element that needs it, because the `error` event doesn't bubble.

Comment: You can add the event handler using a loop in JS, rather than coding it in the HTML on every tag.